# Wordpress change an order in comment form

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I have a comment form like this
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq9g5.png)

I would like to move name/Email inputs above the comment textarea.
 I have tried to find it on google, but I haven't found anything useful.
I am using WordPress version 5.1

Please suggest the way to get my goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
    function comment_override(){
    $comment_args = array('title_reply' => 'Got Something To Say:',
        'fields' => apply_filters('comment_form_default_fields', array(
            'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __('Your Good Name') . '</label> ' . ($req ? '<span>*</span>' : '') .
                '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr($commenter['comment_author']) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
            'email' => '<p class="comment-form-email">' .
                '<label for="email">' . __('Your Email Please') . '</label> ' .
                ($req ? '<span>*</span>' : '') .
                '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr($commenter['comment_author_email']) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' />' . '</p>',
            'url' => '')),
        'comment_field' => '<p>' .
            '<label for="comment">' . __('Let us know what you have to say:') . '</label>' .
            '<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>' .
            '</p>',
        'comment_notes_after' => '',
    );
    return comment_form($comment_args); 
}
remove_action('comments_template');
add_action('comments_template', 'comment_override');
```

Comment: Bro, plz, where should I put this code? To functions.php? I'm new in wordpress

Comment: Yes put this code in functions.php you can arrange the classes and fields according to your need

Comment: Hmm, that put me two comment forms :(

Comment: Updated the answer please check